# AEDT not recognized by NSTimeZone

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nstimezone

AEDT and AEST are real timezones. `NSTimeZone` however thinks otherwise. `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"AEDT"]` returns `nil`.

I've tried `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"AEDT"]` as well, but no luck. How do I get this to work without handling this manually (with fixed timezone offsets)?

Comment: Use the identifiers instead of the abbreviations? For example `"Australia/Sydney"` is a known identifier.

Comment: Sure, but this isn't in my control. Users of our app enter abbreviations such as CET, CEST, GMT, UTC, EST etc and all of those work - except AEDT. The entry field in fact was designed to take in abbreviations (people like to use shorter abbreviations anyway). Why should AEDT not work though?

Comment: I could handle this manually of course, but I wonder what other abbreviations aren't supported. I don't think there's a way to make it work (with AEDT as an abbreviation) so have filed a radar for now, and will internally have to identify and handle this separately. Weird it isn't supported though.

Comment: See [abbreviationDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387258-abbreviationdictionary?language=objc) and the discussion [timeZoneWithAbbreviation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387248-timezonewithabbreviation?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. It's deliberately incomplete, yet unfortunately users prefer to user abbreviations. We'll have to handle this ourselves for now.